# Is there any way to get the Network information of Postman response via code?

Tags: ssl-certificate, postman

I want to check the SSL certification of my sites and calculate the expired date to get notified. But I cannot find out how to pull the information in the network popup above into code. Is there any way that I can get them like `pm.response`, maybe `pm.network`?

Comment: The functionality does not exist at the moment but there is an open feature request to add this into the app.

Comment: Can you give me the link to the feature request ? I wonder if there is any workaround on this.

Comment: The only 'workaround' is to copy the details from the console or the network tab and manually check them. There currently isn't a programmatic way of doing this in the platform. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9689

Comment: Thank you for the information. Guess I have to postpone this task and follow the ticket for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is network information available from response objects within pre-request and post-request (test) scripts:

[image]

However, I am uncertain whether this information applies to your scenario. The title and description of your question don't seem to mesh.

Comment: I want to get those information, and use it in my test. For example, getting the validFrom value and set it to a variable, then use it in my test. But as @danny-dainton mentioned above, it's currently not available.

Comment: You can do that, using the method I described above... If you would like to get in contact with me, I can show you how.